# Prove that $ \neg ( P \iff Q) \equiv \neg P \iff Q $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Prove that $$\neg ( P \iff Q) \equiv \neg P \iff Q$$
What I already tried

On the left side I broke up the material biconditional: $$ \neg[(P \land Q) \land (\neg P \land \neg Q)] $$

And on the right side I did the same thing getting:$$ (\neg P \land Q) \land ( P \land \neg Q) $$

From here on I can use De Morgan's law on the left side but that will only turn the logical ands that I want to keep into logical ors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middle and's should be or's:

$$ \neg[(P \land Q) \lor (\neg P \land \neg Q)] \qquad[1]$$

for the LHS, and

$$ (\neg P \land Q) \lor ( P \land \neg Q) \qquad [2]$$

for the RHS.

Then apply De Morgan's Laws for negation to $[1]$ and use the distributive property to reduce to $[2]$.  Remember $P \land \neg P=$False and False$\lor S=S$ for all propositions $S$.

---

From your comment, I assume you have done this step:

\begin{eqnarray}
&\,\,&\neg[(P \land Q) \lor (\neg P \land \neg Q)] \\&=&(\neg P\lor \neg Q)\land(P\lor Q)
\end{eqnarray}

The next step is \begin{eqnarray}&\,\,&(\neg P\lor \neg Q)\land(P\lor Q)\\&=&
(\neg P \land P) \lor (\neg P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land P)
\end{eqnarray}

Now you are almost there.

Comment: If I do De Morgan's Law on the left side I'll get a logical and in the middle when what I need is a logical or.

Comment: Right, but then use that $\land$ distributes over $\lor$ to get the desired logical or in the middle.  When you multiply out using distributivity you will get four propositions connected by logical or's.  However two of them vanish for the reasons I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I dont understand what "∧  distributes over ∨ " means. Can you show me how the next step would look?

Comment: I have done the next step.